# Convert Objective-C block to Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios8

I am simply trying to convert this Objective-C block to swift but there seems to be a problem, I am unable to solve. None of the variables are optional.

**Objective-C - Works**

```
[CLPlacemark hnk_placemarkFromGooglePlace:place
            apiKey:YOUR_API_KEY
            completion:^(CLPlacemark *placemark, NSString *addressString, NSError *error) {           
        }];
```

**Swift - Gives error**

```
CLPlacemark.hnk_placemarkFromGooglePlace(placeAtIndexPath(indexPath),"YOUR_API_KEY",
completion:{ (placemark:CLPlacemark!, addressString: NSString!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

            })
```

**Error Message:**

```
Cannot invoke 'hnk_placemarkFromGooglePlace' with an argument list of type '(HNKGooglePlacesAutocompletePlace!, String, completion: (CLPlacemark!, NSString!, NSError!) -> Void)'
```

**Swift Method Signature**

```
 CLPlacemark.hnk_placemarkFromGooglePlace(place:
 HNKGooglePlacesAutocompletePlace!, apiKey:String!, completion:
 ((CLPlacemark!, String!, NSError!) -> Void)
```

Comment: Not a duplicate... Anyway I can't see whats wrong - your best bet is to look at the auto generated swift api for the CLPlacemark.  E.g. right click and 'Jump to definition' - if you dont see the error, post the swift method signature in your question

Answer (score 0):

Swift bridges NSString to String in blocks. You still use NSString in your callback, but should use String.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Swift 1.2 (or maybe even 1.1) String and NSString are compatible, but the compiler requires that you cast them. Think something like: `NSString(string: mySwiftString)` or `String(myNSString)`. The error shows that you're using both a `String` and `NSString`, make sure you're using the right one in the right places.